# Running out of Memory when building Stanza Document

Tags: jupyter-notebook, out-of-memory, stanford-nlp, nvidia-jetson

System Specifications: - Device:- NVIDIA Jetson AGX Xavier [16 GB] - Jetpack 4.5.1
8 core CPU
RAM:- 32 GB
The Pipeline looks like

```
nlp = stanza.Pipeline('en', use_gpu=True, batch_size=100, tokenize_batch_size = 32, pos_batch_size = 32, , depparse_batch_size = 32)

doc = nlp(corpus)
```

I am trying to build a Stanza Document with processors:- tokenizer, pos, depparse, error, sentiment, ner;
While using a dataset of around 300MB of txt to build the Stanza Document i am running out of memory (RAM) and then the jupyter notebook stops and kernel dies, even with 100MB of data the kernel dies.
(I have tried using higher batch sizes and even lower as well but the problem persists)